# Como puedo reestructurar el método GetDonwloadUrl() obsoleto en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

El codigo que me produce error es el siguiente

```
public void createOrUpdateProfileWithImage(final Profile profile, Uri imageUri, final OnProfileCreatedListener onProfileCreatedListener) {
    String imageTitle = ImageUtil.generateImageTitle(UploadImagePrefix.PROFILE, profile.getId());
    UploadTask uploadTask = databaseHelper.uploadImage(imageUri, imageTitle);

    if (uploadTask != null) {
        uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl();
                LogUtil.logDebug(TAG, "successful upload image, image url: " + String.valueOf(downloadUrl));

                profile.setPhotoUrl(downloadUrl.toString());
                createOrUpdateProfile(profile, onProfileCreatedListener);

            } else {
                onProfileCreatedListener.onProfileCreated(false);
                LogUtil.logDebug(TAG, "fail to upload image");
            }

        });
    } else {
        onProfileCreatedListener.onProfileCreated(false);
        LogUtil.logDebug(TAG, "fail to upload image");
    }
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

El reemplazo a este metodo deprecado es usar Task ya que ahora todas las operaciones de Firebase devuelven un Task

```
 UploadTask uploadTask = image_path.putFile(mainImageURI);

                uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                            throw task.getException();
                        }
                        return image_path.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Uri downloadUrl = task.getResult();
                            Log.i("URL : ", downloadUrl.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```